# How to have Visual Studio Code open a Github project's specific file automatically?

Tags: visual-studio-code, github, settings

### What I want

I want a user of a C++ project to simply:

- install VSC and Docker
- click on a link I give them
- a container is run and dependencies are installed
- when setup is done, VSC opens a specific file `template/main.cpp`
- users edit the code, click on `cmd+shift+P`, then `> Task > Compile and Run` for their script to be properly compiled and executed.

### What I could do

The tasks are defined in `.vscode/tasks.json` and I get VSC opening and the devcontainer running when clicking this link:
https://vscode.dev/redirect?url=vscode://ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers/cloneInVolume?url=https://github.com/Quetzal-framework/quetzal-CoaTL .

### What remains:

However I would like the VSC editor to direct me automatically to the `template/main.cpp` file. Is there a way to do that using the settings in `.vscode/settings.json` ?

Comment: without any extensions or manual action by the user? as far as I know, no.